# FIlter data with Spring coming from request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, request

I have some infromation coming from request such as:

```
http://localhost:9080/online/accounts/list/usersQuery?filter=uid&value=ab
```

And I have to treat this in Spring where the object is `uid` and the filter value is `ab`

So far I have the folowing code in `Spring`:

```
@RequestMapping(produces="application/json", value = "/usersQuery", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody PagedResources<Resource<UserDetails>> listItemsSortQuery(@PageableDefault(size = 20, page = 0) Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<UserDetails> assembler) {


    Page<UserDetails> lstUserDetails = userDetailsRepository.findAll(pageable);

    return assembler.toResource(lstUserDetails);
}
```

But it doesn't consider nothing about those two values.

What should I change in order to filter data according to the field `uid` and filter data `ab` ?

The `uid` is the `user id` in the `user` object and I need to pick all the users that have an `id` containing `ab`

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: I don't understand _I have to treat this in Spring where the object is uid and the filter value is ab_. What do you mean? In `@RequestMapping`, you can specify attribute `params = {"uid=ab"}`

Comment: I don't think my comment was relevant to your use case.

Comment: Do you want to get *uid* value in you method in order to filter your data?

Comment: Much better if you don't know which filter will come in order to get it from your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting uid value with @RequestParam

```
    @RequestMapping(produces="application/json", value = "/usersQuery", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody PagedResources<Resource<UserDetails>> listItemsSortQuery(@PageableDefault(size = 20, page = 0) Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<UserDetails> assembler, 
  @RequestParam("filter")String filter, @RequestParam("value")String value) {


        Page<UserDetails> lstUserDetails = userDetailsRepository.findByFilter(pageable, filter, value);

        return assembler.toResource(lstUserDetails);
    }
```

EDITED:

In your repository you need a method to filter your data, i.e.

```
    public interface UserDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<UserDetails, Long> {
           @Query("SELECT u FROM UserDetails u WHERE LOWER(?1) = LOWER(?2)")
           Page<UserDetails> findByFilter(String filter, String value, Pageable pageable);
        }
```

Comment: Don't you have any method in your userDetailsRepository to filter your data?. Edited above

Comment: I edited a mistake in the code, pageable is the last parameter. Try now

Comment: No, your filter must be a column in this approach

Comment: You need to know the name of the column you are filtering at this time. You can rename your filter name or convert that name before calling this method